# Auto Clicker - Screen Scraping

Tags: windows, automation

I'm looking for a tool (if any exists) that can capture an image from my computer screen, search for something specific in that image and click on that image. Then after it is clicked, it will then look for something else on the screen continuously (until it is found) and click on that. And after I set all that, I just repeat it in an infinite loop.

My preference would be an actual tool with a GUI since it would eliminate all the trouble needed to set this thing up, however if none exists I would like to ask what would be the best tools out there to code something like this? *Currently I only know about **SikuliX**. but don't know if there are better and simpler solutions for my situation (without the coding).*

Thanks for your time.

The following link is an Android game I play via Bluestacks on my computer:
[Example Link Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMLj0.jpg)